# overlay button progress dialog android

Tags: android, xml, button, progress-bar

Hi I am new to android so today I learn about the progress bar, the goal I try to reach is to create an XML that only contains a progress bar and dialog, and this show in another XML, the error I present is when they make the progress bar show don't block ui so I can be able to click the buttons but the TextView its block, so any help would be appreciated please and thank you
This is mi XLM for progress bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pbText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Please wait ..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my xml for the mainActivity

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />


<include
    android:id="@+id/llProgressBar"
    layout="@layout/load_resource"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the image its see the button over the progress bar

Comment: Your LinearLayout layout_width & layout_height are match_parent. This means that when this layout is included in another layout, it will match its parent's width/height, unless else is specified in your include tag. Add android:layout_width="wrap_content" & android:layout_height="wrap_content" inside your <include> tag.

Comment: Yeah i understand that but the goal i try to reach is this 
https://therajanmaurya.medium.com/progress-bar-instead-progress-dialog-baa5d72c2860, if you see the include Overlays the view but in my case the buttons keep be able to click, In the same way, thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Buttons has default elevation value. This means they are placed above other views sharing the same parent layout.

You can either set a higher elevation value to your LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#CCFFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="10dp">
```

Note that *android:clickable="true"* is also needed in order to block the clicks on the layout below.

The second option would be to wrap the buttons with another (inner) layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"/>
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
    <include
        android:id="@+id/llProgressBar"
        layout="@layout/load_resource"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Using this method you don't need to set elevation to your included layout, but you still need to add *android:clickable="true"*

Comment: Men, you are a genius!
Work perfectly @gioravered thanks you so much!!!!!!!!!